# How to use comma as tmux's prefix

Tags: tmux

Under screen, I used: 
`bindkey , command` to use the comma as the prefix instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

If I do `set -g prefix` in tmux, it complains saying: `unkown key`

At first, I believed that tmux did not support single keys as prefix, However, I managed to use  <kbd>\</kbd> as a prefix successfully!

How can I do so for the <kbd>,</kbd>?

[Edit] Apparently this works under tmux 1.6, haven't tried it though. Thx  [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan) for the hint :)

Comment: This works in tmux 1.6: `set -g prefix ,`

Comment: Ah, I have tmux 1.5 that should explain it then :) Thx ^^